# StreamReader(string) does not exist in .NET 4.5 for Metro when it is supposed to?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.streamreader.aspx

And: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/f2ke0fzy.aspx

Proof that this is the .NET for Metro Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx

There is a constructor for specifying a file path.  Yet in Object Broswer & in the meta data it does not exist.

And apparently all .NET for Metro things are referenced in the References Tab.

I am simply trying to access a txt file from the Project Folder, nothing more.  If anyone has an alternative I am all ears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"This is one of the fundamental changes in WinRT. You can't just write a file anywhere you want anymore, you have to use isolated storage. And you need to use asynchronous I/O with the await keyword."

This link should provide you with the necessary information on how to access files in your project folder. Here is the link:

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html

Comment: There is no IsolatedStorage in WinRT, only Windows.Storage, so I guess it should be referred as Local/Roaming etc storage.

So if this is a fundamental change....why not mention that in the API rather than throwing off a lot of MSDN users.

Comment: well that is an excellent question, which seems I cannot answer

Comment: That link is no longer working. This seems like the new one: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html

Comment: thx for providing a new link. I have updated the answer accordingly